# has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource express react client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

Tryed a couple links here, some tutorials and documentations and running after my tail because i'm not getting anywhere.

Service code:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router()

app.use(json());
app.use(router);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
var server_host = process.env.YOUR_HOST || '0.0.0.0';

const corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://swapee-interface.vercel.app/', 'https://app.swapee.io'] 
}

app.listen(PORT, server_host, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening on port: ${PORT}`)
})

router.get('/:chain/:dex/:token', cors(corsOptions), async(req, res) =>{
 //some logic
})
```

Client code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            url: `https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/${items.chain}/${items.dex}/${items.address}`,
            method: 'get',
        })
        .then((res) => { 
            console.log(res)
            setTokenPrice(res.data) })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            url: `https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/${items.chain}/${items.dex}/${address}`,
            method: 'get',
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                setCoinPrice(response.data)})
      // empty dependency array means this effect will only run once (like componentDidMount in classes)
      }, []);
```

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/137/Quickswap/0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Maybe i need to be specific about the methods that i'm allowing but i think that i already tryed.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight ?

Comment: I think the headers are missing from the response of: 'https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/' not localhost:3000. if you do not control 'https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/' you cannot change this

Comment: @DominicJohnstonWhiteley i do control the api

Comment: @RodrigoBurgos try putting `router.options('/:chain/:dex/:token',cors(corsOptions));` before the `router.get('/:chain/:dex/:token')` or maybe just `router.options('/',cors(corsOptions));` since :chain etc is a parameter

Comment: @DominicJohnstonWhiteley they are params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either try this:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var server_host = process.env.YOUR_HOST || '0.0.0.0';

app.listen(PORT, server_host, () => {
  console.log(`server is listening on port: ${PORT}`);
});

app.get('/:chain/:dex/:token', async (req, res) => {
  //some logic
});
```

Or this:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var server_host = process.env.YOUR_HOST || '0.0.0.0';

const corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    'https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://swapee-interface.vercel.app/',
    'https://app.swapee.io',
  ],
};

app.listen(PORT, server_host, () => {
  console.log(`server is listening on port: ${PORT}`);
});

app.get('/:chain/:dex/:token', cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  //some logic
});
```

Comment: ´´´https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/ ´´´

is the url of the api

And i tryed cors middleware but still not working :'(

Comment: Does it work in the local environment?

Comment: Neither production

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/56/Pancake/0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82' from origin 'https://swapee-interface.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://swapee-api.herokuapp.com/43114/Traderjoe/0xB31f66AA3C1e785363F0875A1B74E27b85FD66c7' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' h

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

CORS policy is checking your request URL with 'Referer' Header from headers (you can't change Referer Header). And if its same as with your server URL allowing the request, otherwise throwing exception. To pass over that you can add webpack configuration to your webpack.config.js file like that.

```
devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    proxy: {
      '/': 'http://localhost:5000',
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

Under the proxy property, you can add your server URL and probably you would't encounter CORS policy.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS